# Hint Path is messing up Nuget Restore

Tags: visual-studio, csproj

I've got 3 projects in my solution; Api, Tests and Tests.Acceptance. When I bring the solution down from Git the Test and Test.Acceptance files fail to restore.

I've tried adding a `.nuget\NuGet.config\` with the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="C:\packages" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

And while that seems to pull the packages into that folder the actual solutions themselves are not heeding the config.

I have not run a `Update-Package -reinstall` on the project, is this a necessary step in getting the csproj files to obey the new `NuGet.config`?

Comment: Are you certain that the `packages.config` file is present in the projects it doesn't work? What is the error that you are seeing?

Comment: @MartinUllrich I'm certain. This solution works locally but when pushed to github and downloaded and unzipped it fails. The error is a CS0246 - saying the namespaces cannot be found, this is because the references are not being found for the nuget packages.

Comment: And how did you restore the solution after unzipping? through VS or `nuget.exe restore`? what is the `<HintPath>` value? (also: which VS / nuget version are we talking about?)

Comment: @MartinUllrich I restored the solution by right clicking the solution and selecting nuget restore, I then ran `Update-Package -reinstall` which just repointed my hintpaths to the correct place. NuGet Package Manager is v3.5. After adding the NuGet.config and running `Update-Package -reinstall` the hintpaths changed to the new location. It's not really idea but it should work better for anyone downloading the project.

Answer (score 3):

You are right that the `HintPath` will confuse other users when cloning a project in a few scenarios like an absolute repository path that is specified in a user's nuget config that is not overridden by the project. As long as everyone uses the same `repositoryPath` - either through a global config or a NuGet.Config file in the solution folder -, this shouldn't be a problem.

If you want to support a wide variety of these configs, I suggest moving off packages.config and use the new `PackageReference` nuget mechanism in VS 2017 / NuGet 4 where the csproj file itself lists the packages it needs and does not contain any hint paths. Furthermore, a global package cache will be used for all projects. Refer to [NuGet's blog post](http://blog.nuget.org/20170316/NuGet-now-fully-integrated-into-MSBuild.html) on the integration, especially the section [What about other project types that are not .NET Core?](http://blog.nuget.org/20170316/NuGet-now-fully-integrated-into-MSBuild.html#what-about-other-project-types-that-are-not-net-core) (Note that the mechanism is fully supported in the currently released VS 2017 version)